# Not able to ssh to aws ec2 instance using config and doing key less ssh

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ssh, 20.10, aws

My config file is located at `/home/vidur/.ssh/config` and its content is:

```
Host ec2
     HostName 54.69.86.125 
     User ubuntu
     Identity /home/vidur/Documents/SSH_PEM_FILES/tukacloud.pem

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  UseKeychain yes
```

When I run:

```
ssh ec2
```

Gives the following error:

```
home/vidur/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: identity
/home/vidur/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Can you please guide me for the correct configuration I am using Ubuntu 20 both in local Ubuntu and remote AWS machine.

However, simple SSH with key present in the command will work.

```
ssh -i tukacloud.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-69-86-125.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Host ec2
    HostName 54.69.86.125
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile /home/vidur/Documents/SSH_PEM_FILES/tukacloud.pem

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  UseKeychain yes
```